# Issues with user interaction on UIScrollView on another page

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, user-interaction

I have a `UIScrollView` with 3 pages.  The problem is that in my app the user must be able to interact with all the pages at the same time, and for some reason it appears that there's some automatic functionality that disables the user interaction on the pages that are not currently being seen.  I need to disable this in order to allow interactions with all the views in my scroll view, on all pages.

Comment: What interaction are you referring to that the user can do with UI items that are not visible on the screen?

Comment: the thing is that they are visible on the screen. The interactions consist on that the UIbuttons on the UIScrollView respond as they should.

Comment: If all UI Items are visible on screen, why do you use the paging mode?